# What is the workflow for automount in Gnome 2.30?

Tags: gnome, fedora, dbus, udev, automount

I have a ASUS laptop with Fedora 13. My problem is that any USB storage I connect does not automount. I have other computer with Fedora 13 which does not have the problem.

I have not be able to find any difference in configuration between my laptop and other computers that work.

So to try to trace down the problem I started to looomk for documentation on how it was supposed to work. I have looked at udev, devkit, hal , dbus, polkit, gnome and others.

I want to know which events, logs, config files and monitor programs that I can use to track down the events that takes place from when I attach an USB stick and until i have a window up and running in GNOME.

So far I have traced that udev detects the disk and creates /dev/sdb (and /dev/sdb1 for partition 1) and that event about device added is sent as messages on dbus. I am able to mount the disk manually with udisks but not with gnome-disk-utility (palmiset).

There is many different applications involved to automount a disk, I want to find out where in the chain of events does it fail.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just found the reason it did not mount. I had a leftover file from earlier udev version. File 60-persistent-storage.rules existed in both /etc/udev/rules.d and in /lib/udev/rules.d . The former overruled the last one. When removing the one in /etc/udev/rules.d the USB drives mounted correctly again.